# Add view function is not working in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Whenever I right-click on `return View()` in a controller method to add a view, I get an error.

Previously it was showing an error to turn Fusion!Log to 1. Something like that. I was done with it. But then it shows another error:

[image]

Comment: it may be because of working with multiple version of Visual Studio. which one you are using?

Comment: visual studio 2017 community version

Answer (score 0):

Error is showing  System.Text.Encoding is missing in your reference. please add dll using tools->nuget package manager->package manager console and run the following command.

```
Install-Package System.Text.Encoding -Version 4.3.0
```

after that rebuild your solution and try. Thank you